# I can't make setTimeout() work in my script

Tags: javascript

I'm making a memory game. It already sort of works, but when I choose two cards that aren't the same picture, they flip back instantly, without showing the user what is on the second card. I think I should use setTimeout(), but for now it only made my flipBack() function not work at all. Maybe, I am using it incorrectly or in the wrong place.

I tried putting both the flipBack() and setTimeout(flipBack, 5000) inside "else if", outside of it, outside of my revealCard() function.

I'm only getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
at flipBack (memory game.js:61:35)" in the console. It seems that setTimeout cannot execute flipBack() or something like that.

```
let board = document.getElementById("board");
let score = document.getElementById("score");
let fails = document.getElementById("fails");
let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");



// add eventListener to every card
for (let i =  0; i < 6; i++) {
    cards[i].addEventListener("click", revealCard);
}

let revealCounter = 2;
let imgAltArray = [];
let latestTwoRevealedCards = [];
let points = 0;
let wrongGuesses = 0;

function revealCard(event) {
    if (revealCounter > 0) {
        let cardImg = event.target.firstChild;
        // make card "flip", so you can see the picture
        cardImg.style.visibility = "visible";

        imgAltArray.push(cardImg.alt);
        latestTwoRevealedCards.push(cardImg);
        console.log(imgAltArray);
        
        revealCounter--;
        // check if both cards have the same picture on them by comparing alt parameters
        if (revealCounter == 0 && imgAltArray[0] === imgAltArray[1]) {
            imgAltArray = [];
            latestTwoRevealedCards = [];
            points++
            score.textContent = `Score: ${points}`;
            revealCounter = 2;
        }
        else if (revealCounter == 0 && imgAltArray[0] !== imgAltArray[1]) {
            wrongGuesses++;
            fails.textContent = `Failed attempts: ${wrongGuesses}`
            imgAltArray = [];
            // make cards flip back
            setTimeout(flipBack, 5000);
            
            

            
            latestTwoRevealedCards = [];
            revealCounter = 2;
           
        }
        
        
    }    
}

// TIMEOUT DOESN"T WORK

function flipBack() {
    for (let i = 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        latestTwoRevealedCards[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there are at least 2 elements in `latestToRevealedCars`?

Comment: there aren't, because just after the `setTimeout` call, he sets `latestTwoRevealedCards = [];` so when the function actually get called that's empty. try move `latestTwoRevealedCards = [];
            revealCounter = 2;` in your `flipBack` function, after the for loop

Comment: Check the `revealCounter > 0` it must be `true`, and the second condition `revealCounter == 0 && imgAltArray[0] === imgAltArray[1]` should be `false`. Then the `setTimeout` will start, simple the way of debugging.

Comment: @coglialoro that worked, I didn't consider the fact that code after setTimeout won't wait with execution before setTimeout uses flipBack().

Comment: @AmerllicA Those conditions are being met. Function flipBack() does work without setTimeout.

Comment: @JakeRedgrave, sometime it happens, sometime during some actions of browsers some changes couldn't be implemented truly, so by adding a `setTimeout(flipBack, 0)` you could send the `flipBack` to `event loop` and in async queue, then you will have it truly, it's a common solution.

Answer (score 0):

`latestTwoRevealedCards[i]` This element may be `undefined`